# How do I write Big O-notations

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I don´t really know how to express in big O-notation. I´ve seen several sources talking about this but it only made me more uncertain. When I write in big-O should I just ignore the constants?

examples:

```
1. 0.02N³
2. 4N*log(2^N)
3. 24Nlog(N)
4. N²
5. N*sqrt(N)
```

this is what I mean with "ignore the constants":

```
1. O(N³)
2. O( N*log(2^N) )
3. O( Nlog(N) )
4. O( N² )
5. O( N*sqrt(N) )
```

and how fast are `O( N*log(2^N) )` and `O( N*sqrt(N) )` growing compared to the other examples?

I really appreciate the help so thanks in advance

Comment: To see which is largest, it generally works to calculate the value (`N*log(2^N)` or `N*sqrt(N)`) for some large N and see what you get for each.

Comment: Note that log(2^N) = N*log(2) - and log(2) is a constant.

Comment: @fgb ... thus `O(N*log(2^N))` = `O(N*N*log(2))` = `O(N^2)` (in case someone missed that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big O notation is characterizes asymptotic behavior of function. Mathematically `f(x) = O(g(x))` when `lim (x->inf) (f(x)/g(x)) = const`

Let's get some clarity. There are 5 common notations ([Bachmann–Landau notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)):

```
 ω (small omega)
 Ω (big omega)
 Θ (theta)
 Ο (big o)
 ο (small o)
```

They works like mathematical comparison operators:

```
 < (strictly less)
 <= (less or equals)
 = (equals)
 >= (greater or equals)
 > (strictly greater)
```

Strictly saying, big o is just an upper bound so you can't say which function grows faster based just on big-o notation.

For example, quick sort has worst case complexity = O(n<sup>2</sup>) but it's also right to say that quick sort has worst case complexity = O(n<sup>889</sup>).
It's just like we can say x < 899 based on knowledge that x < 2.

Because of the limiting behavior you can ignore constants and less-ordered summands (they are "dominated" by the highest order summand) of your functions.
For example, if `f(x) = 33*n³ + n² + n + 3544`, it's right to say that `f(x) = O(n³)` 
(Moreover, it's right to say `f(x) = Θ(n³)` which is much more informative (`Θ` is called a `tight bound`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you ignore the constants. Also if you have a sum ex. `5n^2 + 2n` you only take the biggest argument with highest exponent (also without the constant) -> here: `O(n^2)`  
You did those examples good. 
To compare the growing, I suggest you use wolframalpha or any tool drawing plots, and you will see how they change