# Equality of complexities

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

Is it true that O(nlogn) is also O(n^2), and also is it false that omega(nlogn) is also omega(n^2)
Thanks

Comment: False : O(nlogn) is also O(n^2).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Huh?  O(nlogn) **is** a subset of O(n^2).

Comment: i dont get it, do you mean that O(nlogn) is also 0(n^2) is false?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry! I thought he is saying = (equal) My mistake

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Ah, yes, I guess it depends exactly what the OP is asking.

Comment: so, i still did not get the answer, i think if an algorithm is o(nlogn), it is also O(n^2), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`O(n log n)` is less than `O(n ^ 2)`: if you divide them, then `n log n / n ^ 2 = log n / n = 0` if `n -> infinity`. Since their ratio doesn't converge to 1 but to 0, they're not equivalent complexities.

Comment: i did not get it, if an algorithm is o(nlogn), then that means it is smaller than equal to nlogn, doesn't it mean that it is also smaller than o(n^2) since n^2 is greater than o(nlogn)?

Comment: @copy_constructor That's true, but that's why we don't use the definition for tasks like this. (Read Wikipedia's article on the Big-Oh notation, it's nicely explained there.)

Comment: i just had a true-false question in the exam and wanted to be sure. So, is it true that an O(nlogn) algorithm is also O(n^2)?

Comment: @copy_constructor Well, you now rephrased the question. Like that, it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Ο is a class of functions that have an equivalent limiting behavior. A function *g*‍(*n*) ∈ Ο(*f*‍(*n*)) means that for *n* ⟶ ∞, ***f* does not grow significantly faster than *g***.

In this respect, the statement of f(*n*) = *n*·log *n* ∈ Ο(*n*<sup>2</sup>) is true as *n*·log *n* does not grow significantly faster than *n*<sup>2</sup>.

But generally, these notations are used to describe the nearest bounds. So if a function is in Ο(*n*·log *n*), you wouldn’t use Ο(*n*<sup>2</sup>) to describe its limiting behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295113/how-do-i-write-big-o-notations/14295290#14295290) about asymptotic notation.
The answer is yes `Ο(nlg(n))⊂Ο(n^2)` But not the converse (`Ο(n^2)⊄Ο(nlg(n))`)

`f(x) ∈ Ο(nlg(n))` states that `lim(x->inf) (f(x)/Ο(nlg(n)))` is const (may be 0).
For small omega notation `f(x) ∈ ω(nlg(n))` means that `lim(x->inf) (f(x)/ω(nlg(n)))` is infinity. (ω is called a lower bound) so you are right, `ω(nlg(n))⊄ω(n^2)`